# Selenium webdriver-Junit- Read and Write in same excel

Tags: selenium, junit, webdriver

Selenium webdriver-Junit- Read and Write in same excel

Read inputs from excel file
Compare o/p in (application Vs one of the cell in the excel)
Write test case passed in last row of excel if the comparison is success

All needs to be done in same excel. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can find this data in the following link

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html

Where the java code also works in Junit.But you must download Jxl.jar file from

http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jars/jxl-2.6.jar

to perform any excel operations through Junit.

Always save the excel file in ***Excel 97-2003 Workbook***.Otherwise we cannot open excel in Junit.